# HTML 5 Boilerplate - Issues with IE?

Tags: internet-explorer, html, css, boilerplate

I usually code all website projects by scratch but I decided to use boilerplate for a new project after checking out the source code etc...

The set-up is great and the code is solid but I am having problems with IE that I may just be overlooking but I can't seem to solve the issue. Basically, the site displays perfect on every browser and phones etc but will not display anything for IE... The only thing that IE displays is the body background??

Basically because I can't post the website because of the client (they are quite high profile where I am from) I am just checking if this is a common problem?? Is there a quick fix??

I know I'm not giving much information I'm just looking to see if this is a common fix or if it's something I'll have to look into...

Thanks for any help!

EDIT - Here is my doc head:

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js ie6 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js ie7 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js ie8 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

    <script src="js/libs/modernizr-2.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/libs/respond.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://use.typekit.com/lyx5qmg.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">try{Typekit.load();}catch(e){}</script>
</head>
```

Comment: I'd usually expect a couple of inconsistencies between browsers, but the entire site content not displaying? Which version of Internet Explorer are you testing with?

Comment: Hi Anthony, testing using 6,7 and 8. Nothing is being displayed. Strange thing is, the links are there? When I roll my mouse over the body background, the hyperlinks are activated. It's as if the container div is invisible!?...

Answer (score 2):

On google's site at: (dead link) https://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/issues/detail?id=24# it says the problem is with the url.  A gentleman named Richard Bland indicated a correction:

> ```
> !--[if lt IE 9]>
> <script src=**"http://**html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
> <![endif]-->
> ```

Please note, I am quoting the gentleman from that website.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I solved it by downloading and referencing an updated version of Modernizr here http://www.modernizr.com/ - I guess 2.0 just doesn't cut it anymore :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using IE8 or earlier, you'll need to use [HTML5 Shiv](http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv) to make IE understand the new HTML5 tags. Simply add this code to your `<head>` and it should work:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="//html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Hi Adam, boilerplate uses modernizr. I can supply my doc-head. I'll post it in my original post.

Comment: @Andrew233 Ah yes, my bad, I forgot about that. Please share the head and I will have a look.

Comment: Thanks for posting the document head, I'll do some tests now.

Comment: Ok, I've had a bit of a play around with the boilerplate in IE8 and it all worked. Can you please press F12 in IE to enter Developer Tools, then go to the scripts tab to see if there are any errors in the console on the right?

Comment: @Andrew233 It could be. Try commenting out the typekit scripts at the bottom of the head, does it make a difference? Because it might be something with their fonts that is causing a problem on your page.

Comment: Still no joy, seems strange... I used the initializr to generate a custom set-up for boilerplate. I never touched any of the frame styles, I just added my own which work perfectly on every browser.

Comment: @Andrew233 Try commenting out anything that you've added yourself (apart from the content in the body). Then, one-by-one, remove the comment tags from the things you added. Tell me what code you uncommented that causes the page to not display anything in IE.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, with HTML5 you don't need the `type` attribute on the `script` element.

Secondly, close your `link stylesheet` element. IE is a lot less tolerant of such things so chances are this is causing it to not see the stylesheet at all.

Comment: HTML5 doesn't allow self closing tags... Also, you don't need to close the link stylesheet element...

Comment: I have always used link tags without closing them and they have not created any problems in IE (or at least in IE6 to IE10) so that couldn't be the problem.

Comment: It was worth a try, as who knows with Internet Explorer! And @andrew233, your statement "HTML5 doesn't allow self closing tags" is completely untrue.

Comment: Sorry, let me rephrase it, HTML5 doesn't require self closing tags on the tags you are referencing, i.e. a non-void element.

Comment: Which is completely different to what you said the first time around. Regarding the issue at hand, do you have the code available anywhere online for us to take a look at?

Comment: Hi Ian, I couldn't post the link publicly, I could probably post it then remove it after you take a look? Let me know when your reading this and i'll post it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I posted it, did you get it? Your from Ireland, you'll probably know the place.

Comment: Well that's odd. I have IE9 and tried it in IE 8 and 7 modes also and everything works fine for me (nice site by the way). Even tried it in IETester and it was fine!

Comment: Very strange... must be a local problem. I've tested it on our in-studio windows and using sauce labs scout system. Will it work for you using the sauce labs scout system? Here is the link: http://saucelabs.com/. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I get an error when I try that: An security error occured (Error #2048). Check your policy-policy server configuration or disable security for this domain.

Comment: Yeah, I'm getting that too. Thanks for your help, I can guess it's maybe a server/local issue, I'll try switching it to another server and try it.

Comment: Ok, feel free to contact me at: ian [at] iandevlin.com

Comment: OK, I've actually never seen this before. When I hit print preview, the content appears and prints fine! However, it doesn't display?

Comment: OK, found out what is causing the problem... It's the chrome frame prompt code in the 2.0 boilerplate update... Not sure why this is doing what it's doing? This is the code I removed and it worked. <!--[if lt IE 7 ]>
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/chrome-frame/1.0.2/CFInstall.min.js"></script>
 <script>window.attachEvent("onload",function(){CFInstall.check({mode:"overlay"})})</script>
<![endif]-->

Comment: At lease you sorted it! It might be worth posting it as a bug?

Comment: I'm now not 100% sure this is the issue. It now seems to come on then when I refresh it disappears. Then when I shut down IE and restart and try it, it appears fine...