# Initializr template not rendering correctly in IE 8

Tags: html, internet-explorer, html5boilerplate

I am creating a new site using the [Initializr template](http://www.initializr.com/try). It looks great on modern web browsers. I though it was optimized for compatability but when I open it in Internet Explorer 8 (a browser I must unfortunarly support) it looks like this:

[image]

As you can see the tab navigation is not rendering properly.

I am using the default:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->

<html class="no-js">
<!--<![endif]-->
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">

    <script src="js/vendor/modernizr.custom.82220.js"></script>
</head>
```

The only difference above is that I tried updating modernizr to see if it would fix the problem but the result is the same. How can I get HTML5 boilerplate to render correctly in IE 8?

Comment: `<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
 <![endif]-->` <-- that can help

Comment: instead of modernizr or including?

Comment: you can read more here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7282580/html-5-boilerplate-issues-with-ie

Comment: modernizr already includes html5shiv

Comment: Yeah, including the html5shiv and modernizr is just a waste of a connection and a waste of bytes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was resolved adding this to the css page:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) {
    .lt-ie9 nav a { margin: 0 0.7%; }
}
```